# If statement Matlab

Tags: matlab, if-statement, matrix

I have the following code

```
for a = 1:38;
    for b = 1:41;
        if distance(a,b)== 0;
            distance(a,b) == 1;
        end
    end
end
```

Its for a 38x41 matrix. The matrix has numbers and zero values. How do I write an if statement that will convert any zero value to 1. I can't see why the above code will not work.

Regards,
Jer

Comment: The reason your original code doesn't work is that `==` and `=` are different things.  You want `= 1;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can't you do

```
distance(distance==0) = 1;
```

---

```
B =

0.00000   0.06275   0.93469
0.44025   0.39606   0.00000
0.67538   0.78137   0.04386


B(B==0) = 1
B =

1.000000   0.062751   0.934691
0.440246   0.396058   1.000000
0.675376   0.781375   0.043856
```

Comment: Thanks for that! I dont know how i didnt think of that!